# Showing an equivalence relation in Set Optimization

Tags: elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Let $\mathcal{A} \subset \{ X \in \mathcal P \left({Z}\right) | X = X
>  + C \}$ and  $B \in \{ X \in \mathcal P \left({Z}\right) | X = X + C \}$ where + is the usual Minkowski sum.
>
> Define the supremum of a family to be $$\text{sup} \mathcal{A} = \bigcup_{A\in \mathcal{A}} A$$
>
> Then show that the following are equivalent:
>
> $\text{(a) sup} (\mathcal{A}+B) =  \text{sup} (\mathcal{A})+B$
>   $\text{(b) For each } A, B \in \{ X \in \mathcal P \left({Z}\right) | X = X + C \}$, the set $\{ D \in \{ X \in \mathcal P \left({Z}\right) | X = X + C \} | B + D \subset A\}$ has a greatest element with
>   respect to $\subset$.

I found this question in the paper "Set Optimization—A Rather Short Introduction" by Andreas H. Hamel, Frank Heyde, Andreas Löhne, Birgit Rudloff and Carola Schrage.

The (a) $\implies$ (b) is provided in the text, but the converse direction got me stumped.
Any ideas on how to approach the converse direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A bazaar definition of infinum.

Comment: @WilliamElliot  I know. I think it's because they want to solve a minimization problem and so they switched infimum and supremum. I will edit this because it is only relevant to the paper, not to the question.